# What is the use of lambda in the last function here?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to understand Lambda expressions;

I've got a basic function `Sq1` which is squaring the number `i`
I can rewrite this with a lambda to oneline it, `Sq2`

I can also write it like `Sq4` with a Func<>, but I'm not sure why I'd want to

and furthermore, with `Sq3` I was trying to write the long-hand version of `Sq4` because writing `Sq1` helped me understand what `Sq2` was actually doing

```
   public int Sq1(int i)
    {
        return i * i;
    }

    public int Sq2(int i) => i * i;

    public Func<int, int> Sq3(int i)
    {
        // Not sure what goes here, I don't want to return a function?
    }

    public Func<int, int> Sq4 = x => x * x;
```

Can anybody help me understand why I'd write the function as per `Sq4` and what this is actually shorthand for?

Comment: What do you want `Sq3` to do? `Sq4` isn't a function, it's a field

Comment: You need to return a delegate object.  So spelled-out without the confusing syntax sugar: `return new Func<int, int>(Sq1);`  Do note that you have no use for the i argument, that need to be supplied when the calling code invokes the delegate.  Apply sugar from there as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sq1` and `Sq2` are *identical* functions, not lambdas. `Sq2` uses the [expression body syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#expression-body-definitions) that allows simplifying simple methods. `Sq2` is essentially:

```
public int Sq2(int i) {
    return  i * i;
}
```

You can use [Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoATEANQAfAAIAmAIwBYAFAiAzAAJxigMKKA3rMU7lStiUUBlAI4SAFAZiK2ASm26tM3S+UB2G4oBUNgNwOdAF9ZAL0bQ1MxS0M7RQBeAD5PHzZ/Z11QhWUAVgAeK25wmCTTABZ4xQAPeKTqn0q0l1lAoA===) to see the generated code in both cases. You'll see that the body of both methods is the same

You can't make the `Sq3` function behave like `Sq4`, because `Sq4` on the other hand is a  Func-typed *field* that holds the `x => x * x` delegate. `Sq3` on the other hand is a function that returns a `Func`, a common idiom in functional programming.

You can use `Sq4` as if it were a function, eg :

```
var result=Sq4(2);
```

As for Sq3, what you do depends on what you want to do. If you only want to execute the function, use the same syntax as `Sq1` or `Sq2`. If you really want to return a `Func<>` you could use something like this :

```
public Func<int,int> Sq3F()
{
    return (int i)=>i*i;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var fun=Sq3F();
var result=fun(4);
```

**Why a Func<>?**

That doesn't look like much until you realize you can pass *functions* as parameters and construct complex transformations dynamically, eg :

```
public Func<int,double> LogF(Func<int,int> fun)
{
    return (int i)=>Math.Log(fun(i));
}

...

var func=LogF(Sq3F());
var result=func(4);
```

Another common technique is [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) - take a function with multiple arguments and produce another one where some of the arguments are fixed. Let's say you want to create a single-argument Log method that works for a *specific* base, which means you can't just use `Math.Log(double,double). You could do this :

```
public Func<double,double> LogN(double N)
{
    return (double d)=>Math.Log(d,N);
}

...

var log5F=LogN(5);
var result=log5F(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

You would use the lambda expression for the sake of simplicity, to avoid having to write a full function for a simple operation.

And it would translate to the following normal function:

```
public int Sq4(int x):
{
  return x * x;
}
```

Also you have used an arrow function that is different of a lambda.
An arrow function is a way to simplify the body of a function but it has the same structure

```
(string param1, int param2) => {

// To do here

}
```